# shell script to scp from one server to another by choice

Tags: shell, scp

How to copy files from one server to another server? I have 3 servers from which I have to copy files from one server to another server by choice. I know scp is the command to be used but I just wanted to know how to write a shell script which makes me copy files from one server to another service by choice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The best way to write a script is with a text editor.  The best way to ask a question on SO is to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "by choice".  What is that?  What do you want?  Choose what?  The server?  The file(s) to copy?  You want a menu?  You could just modify the command with these.  Explain.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `by choice`?

Comment: by choice means I should be able to choose the server, file to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a script that:

1. Has a static, defined list of three servers.

`list_of_things=(one two three)`

2. Takes as input/argument a file/file path on the local machine

`first_argument=$0
second_argument=$1`

3. Checks that the file exists

`if [ -e first_argument ]`

4. Loops through the list of servers, and uses `scp` to transfer the file to each server.

`for item IN list_of_things; do
    // do something here
then`

Read through a bash scripting tutorial for more guidance: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your response. This scripts automatically copies files to all servers in the list. But my question is this should be done by choice.

Comment: Well, then you can take some kind of argument in that specifies the server you would like to copy the file to. Though at that point, you might as well just use `scp` directly with the file and server you're interested in?